# How many fair labour hours to change a clutck kit of a 2L GWM Steed 4x4

Tags: clutch-plate, steed

How many fair labour hours required ti change a clutch kit of a 2L GWM Steed 4x4 please.

Thank you.

Comment: For those who voted to close, this is not asking for a *cost* of the labor, but rather what the book rate is to calculate the labor charge. This has been discussed in [this Meta thread](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/1340/4152). To the OP, we could use more information, such as the year of the vehicle you are asking about, plus any other supporting information.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, was about to add a comment to that effect.  :)